# Activiti > bpmn : not able to assign candidate group dynamically using variables

Tags: java, liferay, activiti, bpmn

I am running activiti from liferay.
I am trying to set candidate group for user task dynamically for which I have tried below solutions which are not working.
This is for liferay 6.2 CE GA6 and activiti version 5.18.0
Please let me know if I have missed anything or If you have a better solution.

Solution 1 :
Its regarding settting candidate group for a user task using proccess variable.
below is the bpmn code :

```
<userTask id="Review" name="Review"  activiti:candidateGroups=${assignee}>
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:formProperty id="outputTransition" name="output Transition" type="enum">
      <activiti:value id="Approve" name="Approve"></activiti:value>
      <activiti:value id="Reject" name="Reject"></activiti:value>
    </activiti:formProperty>
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

here , assignee is the process variable which is already set.

While executing the workflow, I am getting following exception :

```
13:42:01,326 INFO  [http-bio-8080-exec-10][LiferayGroupsUtil:54] Convert    groups : [ ${assignee} ]
13:42:01,329 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-10][LiferayGroupsUtil:94] Cannot assign task to role ${assignee} com.liferay.portal.NoSuchRoleException: No Role exists with the key {companyId=20155, name=${assignee}}
```

---

Solution 2 :

I also tried below xml code but I am still getting the same exception :
Here, I have the multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics.

```
<userTask id="Review" name="Review"  activiti:candidateGroups=${assignee}>
    <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" 
     activiti:collection="candidateGrp" activiti:elementVariable="assignee" >
    <completionCondition>${nrOfCompletedInstances/nrOfInstances >= 0.6 }</completionCondition>
  </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:formProperty id="outputTransition" name="output Transition" type="enum">
      <activiti:value id="Approve" name="Approve"></activiti:value>
      <activiti:value id="Reject" name="Reject"></activiti:value>
    </activiti:formProperty>
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

---

Solution 3:

I also tried to set the candidate group dynmically using DynamicBpmnService, Please check the code below :
For this approach, I used activiti version 5.19.0
I replaced the activiti engine jar from liferay > tomcat> webapp > activiti-web > web-inf >lib

```
@Override
public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) {
    try {
    EngineServices engineServices = execution.getEngineServices();
    DynamicBpmnService dynamicBpmnService = engineServices.getDynamicBpmnService();
    ObjectNode infoNode = dynamicBpmnService.changeUserTaskCandidateGroup(
              "Review", "Power User", false);
    dynamicBpmnService.saveProcessDefinitionInfo("procDefId", infoNode);
    System.out.println("------saveProcessDefinitionInfo------=saved");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("------error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Power User");
    execution.setVariable("candidateGrp",list);
}
```

I am getting following exception while executing this code :

```
WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-10][ProxyMessageListener:81] org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lportal`.`act_procdef_info`, CONSTRAINT `ACT_FK_INFO_PROCDEF` FOREIGN KEY (`PROC_DEF_ID_`) REFERENCES `act_re_procdef` (`ID_`))
### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionInfoEntity.insertProcessDefinitionInfo-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into ACT_PROCDEF_INFO(ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, REV_, INFO_JSON_ID_)     values(?,             ?,            1,            ?)
### Cause:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  (`lportal`.`act_procdef_info`, CONSTRAINT `ACT_FK_INFO_PROCDEF` FOREIGN KEY  (`PROC_DEF_ID_`) REFERENCES `act_re_procdef` (`ID_`))
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lportal`.`act_procdef_info`, CONSTRAINT `ACT_FK_INFO_PROCDEF` FOREIGN KEY (`PROC_DEF_ID_`) REFERENCES `act_re_procdef` (`ID_`))
### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionInfoEntity.insertProcessDefinitionInfo-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into ACT_PROCDEF_INFO(ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, REV_, INFO_JSON_ID_)     values(?,             ?,            1,            ?)
### Cause:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lportal`.`act_procdef_info`, CONSTRAINT `ACT_FK_INFO_PROCDEF` FOREIGN KEY (`PROC_DEF_ID_`) REFERENCES `act_re_procdef` (`ID_`))
```

I am really not able to proceed.
your quick help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Process:

```
<userTask id="review" name="Review" >
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.activiti.MyDynamicGroupHandler" />
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Listener:

```
public class MyDynamicGroupHandler implements TaskListener {

  public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {

    String assigneeGroup = 'Reviewer'
    ...
    // business logic to set correct assigneeGroup
    ...
    // set candidate group dynamically 
    delegateTask.addCandidateGroup(assigneeGroup); // 
    ...
  }

}
```

**Spring framework example:**

*myListener* is defined in spring bean context.

```
<bean id="myListener" class="org.activiti.MyDynamicGroupHandler"/>
```

Process:

```
<userTask id="review" name="Review">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="${myListener.setCandidateGroup(task, assigneeGroup)}" />
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Listener:

```
public class MyDynamicGroupHandler {

  public void setCandidateGroup(DelegateTask delegateTask, String assigneeGroup) {
    // set candidate group dynamically 
    delegateTask.addCandidateGroup(assigneeGroup); // 
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Or you can use Spring Framework and expression language to propagate process variable to listener execution.

Comment: Hi fersmi, thank you for the input. I have already tried the code snippet that you have provided but even that is not working. because, even though create event is metioned for the listener, listener is executed AFTER the task is created which includes assignment of candidate group to the task. So addCandidateGroup method has no effect.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share an example for spring framework + expression language

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Listener is executed AFTER the task is created. First time when you set candidate group is in listener. The userTask definition has no attribute activiti:candidateGroups. Or if has, you can remove old one by delegateTask.deleteCandidateGroup().